# How to test loading more rows in a table upon scroll?

Tags: protractor

I am testing infinity scroll using protractor on an angular application. The table initially have 50 rows that are displayed upon loading the url. Once I scroll the next 50 rows are displayed. similarly 800-900 rows are displayed. That means I have to scroll atleast 16 to 18 times. There is also some load time of approximately 3 seconds for next 50 rows to be loaded. How do I test this using Protractor?

I am using scroll into View to load the rows.

```
var tableRows = element.all(by.css('tbody tr'));
        let lastCount = 0
        let count = -1
        const go = () => tableRows.count().then(function (rowCount) {
            lastCount = count
            count = rowCount
            console.log("Count:" +count)
            console.log("lastCount: "+lastCount)
            browser.executeScript(e => e.scrollIntoView(), tableRows.last());
            browser.sleep(3000)
            if (lastCount !== count) {
                console.log("going again")
                go()
            }
            else{
                console.log("In Else")

callback();
```

Here is my HTML

```
<tbody infinite-scroll="$ctrl.loadInventories()" infinite-scroll-container="'.table-wrapper'" md-body="" class="md-body ng-isolate-scope">
<!-- ngRepeat: data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder -->
<tr class="" ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder" style="">

<!-- ngRepeat: data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder -->
<tr class="" ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder" style="">

<!-- ngRepeat: data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder -->
<tr class="" ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder" style="">

<!-- ngRepeat: data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder -->
<tr class="" ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder" style="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try taking the `tr` count .If the initial `tr` count is not equal to final `tr` count continue the loop and if the count matches then we can confirm that all the rows are loaded and no more is left. Hope it helps yous

Comment: I tried using the count and it working as expected. But how to come out of the loop. I added my code to the answer. If all the rows are loaded, execution is going inside the else loop and printing In Else. But how to break the loop there are come out

Comment: Updated the answer. Exiting after using callback in the else statement.